# Distance between 2 points and time taken - Speed keeps increasing as the distance get further why?

Tags: pythagorean-triples, kinematics

I am trying to calculate the time taken between 2 points for a game with X and Y coordinates.

When I plot in the actual time taken based on the game data, and the X Y coordinates, I can't find a constant speed between them.

I noticed as the distance get further, the speed seems to increase.

Does anyone know where I got the formula wrong?

I am using a simple pythagoras formula to calculate distance between 2 points

[image]

Comment: This is missing context.  There is no a priori reason why you can't have constant speed, though perhaps the rules of the game preclude it.

Comment: Are those supposed to be experimental data?  Where are the input numbers for $X,Y, T$ coming from?

Comment: If you are accelerating, the farther you go the faster you will go. Why do you think the speed should not increase?

Comment: That is the thing I am trying to find out in the game. How is the march time mechanics calculated? I tried using constant speed which is not the solution. How formula can I use to incorporate acceleration into the whole thing?

Comment: X Y T is from the game itself. 

X Y is from the actual coord of the 2 structures

and T (time) is the actual time the game shows for the March from Structure A to Structure B

Comment: Without knowing how the game is played, there's nothing anyone can say.  Obviously, it is abstractly possible to move at a constant speed, and it is abstractly possible to move at variable speeds.

Comment: Got it. So with the data above there is no way to reverse engineer the formula equation used for the Marching Time taken from X Y coord to another X Y Coord